# Displaying and resizing a GridRow when a certain height of child control is reached

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, nested, scrollviewer

I cannot seem to get my Grid right. I need a layout with two rows, the first row has a dynamic height based on a child grid's height. The second row contains a couple of Buttons, this row has a constant height of 30 pixels. When the content of the child grid has not yet reached a height of 842 pixels, the window should compress to fit the content. Otherwise, it expands based on the child Grid's height.

If the content of the child grid reaches 842 pixels, I wanted to display a scroll bar only for the first Grid row.

I have played around with MinHeight and MaxHeight but nothing has worked so far. Right now, the scroll bar appears far too late and the window doesn't compress when there is no content in the child grid.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="35px" Height="35*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MinHeight="842px" Margin="0,0,0,13" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>               
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        //Many controls here...

        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

EDIT: Added a picture for clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="842" Margin="0,0,0,13">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button  Grid.Row="1">But</Button>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: I cannot see the content of the child grid if I do it like this. The window compresses alright, but it compresses to the point where I can only see the row with the buttons.

Comment: Child grid? You mean the one with the rectangle. If you remove the rectangle the window will shrink to the size of the button. If this is too small add a MinHeight to the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Ok the culprit was the window's max height. I didn't notice it yesterday but it was set to 842px, when I did this I do not remember XD. somehow this caused the contents of the child grid to disappear. when I removed the max height, it worked